# How to validate an email address in a form submitted to PHP

Tags: php, forms, security, validation

I'm making a small user sign up system to try and teach my self some more PHP and MySQL. I've got to this point so far:

```
   <?php

    $errormsg ="";
    if (isset($_POST['adduser'])){

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pword = $_POST['pword'];
    $pword2 = $_POST['pword2'];

    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $email = strip_tags($email);
    $pword = stripslashes($pword);
    $pword = strip_tags($pword);
    $pword2 = stripslashes($pword2);
    $pword2 = strip_tags($pword2);

    if ($email == "") {
        $errormsg ="Error, You must fill in the email box.";
    }
    else if ($pword == "") {
        $errormsg ="Error, You must fill in the password box.";
    }
    else if ($pword2 == "") {
        $errormsg ="Error, You must fill in the repeat password box.";
    }
    else if ($pword != $pword2) {
        $errormsg ="Error, Your passwords don't match!";
    }
    else {
        $errormsg = "Success!";
    }
}
?>
```

This echo's out success at current, I plan to make it add the data into a database once I have finished it.

How do I go about checking if the email is valid? (e.g. is "example@example.com" and not just "rgaegegegege")

Also how secure is this with using stripslashes and tags? What else can I do to make it less hack able?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

The [**`filter_var()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) functions, are one of the easiest  ways to validate emails, urls, and more.

To validate an email you can do:

```
if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === true) {
   // valid
}else {
   echo "Email is NOT valid!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try like this

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];

if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/i", $email)){
      echo 'email is Invalid';

     }
   else {
    echo 'email is correct ';
     }
?>
```

Comment: Is there an advantage over using preg_match over Filter_validate_email?

What I've got atm that doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/StNdP/